# "Invalid formula for groups" when trying to fit a mixed effects model

Tags: r, regression, mixed

I am trying to fit a mixed effects model. I first create a grouped data object:

```
> HC <- groupedData(bid_price ~ factor(Bedroom.s.) | zip_cbsa_name, 
+                                 data = HC) 
> head(HC)
Grouped Data: bid_price ~ factor(Bedroom.s.) | zip_cbsa_name
    Bedroom.s.                           zip_cbsa_name     bid_price
116          3     Chicago-Naperville-Joliet, IL-IN-WI      4.828314
139          3 Miami-Fort Lauderdale-Pompano Beach, FL      4.382027
144          5         Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX      5.164786
234          2    Los Angeles-Long Beach-Santa Ana, CA      4.369448
275          4          Houston-Sugar Land-Baytown, TX      5.220356
301          4     Chicago-Naperville-Joliet, IL-IN-WI      4.867534
```

Then I fit the object:

```
> HC_fm1 <- lme(log_bid_price ~ as.numeric(Bedroom.s.), data = HC)
Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : 
  invalid formula for groups
```

---

I've tried varying how I include "Bedrooms", but that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Comment: Can we expect to find data-object `HC` in some un-named package, or ar you going to supply it with `dput(HC)`?

Comment: you could try adding `random = ~ Bedroom.s. | zip_cbsa_name` to your `lme` call ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   HC_fm1 <- lme(log(bid_price) ~ as.numeric(Bedroom.s.), data = HC)
```